# image resize with window width, but keep ratio

Tags: css, image, resize

Hi I'm working on a image slider. I need an image to resize with the height of its div (which is pretty much the size of the window). Right now, the image has this css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item >img {
    height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

I also tried width:100%. For example, if I only make the window skinnier horizontally (the window height is unchanged), the image itself should not change size, but just have its sides cropped off. But if I make the window skinnier vertically (decrease the window height), the image would resize according to the height.

Sorry if its unclear. Any ideas?

Comment: add a jsfiddle sample please

Answer (score 0):

Try background-size:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
     background-image: url('../../..');
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using background images, but in an <img> tag?